# Regex in Notion

Tags: regex, notion-api

I am new to using regex. I would like to use Notion to create a personal reference manager. My idea is to extract information from one column containing a bibtex entry to another column, that would contain, for instance, the title of the paper.

My idea that worked better so far:

```
replaceAll(
    replaceAll(prop("Bibtex"), "^((.|\n)*)[tT]itle(\\s|.*)=(\\s|.*){", ""),
    "}((.|\n)*)",
    ""
)
```

but it fails if the title has any curly brackets. For instance, the Bibtex entry

```tex
@article{xu2015experimental,
    title = {Experimental Detection of a Majorana Mode in the core of a Magnetic Vortex inside a Topological Insulator-Superconductor ${\mathrm{Bi}}{2}{\mathrm{Te}}{3}/{\mathrm{NbSe}}_{2}$ Heterostructure},
    author = {Xu, Jin-Peng and Wang, Mei-Xiao and Liu, Zhi Long and Ge, Jian-Feng and Yang, Xiaojun and Liu, Canhua and Xu, Zhu An and Guan, Dandan and Gao, Chun Lei and Qian, Dong and Liu, Ying and Wang, Qiang-Hua and Zhang, Fu-Chun and Xue, Qi-Kun and Jia, Jin-Feng},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
    volume = {114}, issue = {1},
    pages = {017001},
    numpages = {5},
    year = {2015},
    month = {Jan},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.017001},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.017001} }
```

becomes

```tex
@article{xu2015experimental,
   title = {Experimental Detection of a Majorana Mode in the core of a Magnetic Vortex inside a Topological Insulator-Superconductor ${\mathrm{Bi
```

instead of

```tex
Experimental Detection of a Majorana Mode in the core of a Magnetic Vortex inside a Topological Insulator-Superconductor ${\mathrm{Bi}}{2}{\mathrm{Te}}{3}/{\mathrm{NbSe}}_{2}$ Heterostructure
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: chuck into your question some sample data and the expected output.  Also, you can try using https://regex101.com/ to share examples.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Just the title after the "title={"? Please edit your post to show example good and bad titles please.

Comment: Your question is so unclear it's not answerable, so it's been closed. What exactly do you mean by "just the title"? From your only example, do you want `Majorana zero modes in impurity-assisted vortex of LiFeAs 
superconductor` or `title={Majorana zero modes in impurity-assisted vortex of LiFeAs 
superconductor}`? You mention problems with curly brackets in titles, but have not shown an example. Please edit your question to improve clarity, remove irrelevancies and add several examples of kinds of input and what you want matched from them. Then vote to reopen.

Comment: Hi, I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, make the match for any character or newline non-greedy and anchor to the start of the line.

```
^[tT]itle={((.|\n)*?)},
```

[regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/qmdPc8/1)

Edit:  This works for also for the new example (allowing for optional whitespace before the word title and around the equal sign):

```
^\s*?[tT]itle\s?=\s?{((.|\n)*?)},
```